# Adding decimal degree reference grid in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, grids-graticules

How do I add a decimal degree reference grid to ArcMap that is multiples of 2?

See attached photos for what I have vs. what I would like. I have tried changing the interval under data frame properties but have had no luck.

[image: what I have]

[image: What I want]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to place a graticule (a [reference grid is different](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/adding-a-reference-grid.htm)) on your data frame.  What were the settings (show another picture) you used on the Interval tab of your Data Frame Properties when you produced the map in your first picture?

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest that I could achieve...
[image: example map]

Create a new **Graticule** grid.  You can use the default values initially as you can modify them after the grid is created.  An interval of 7.2 seconds is equivalent to 0.002 decimal degrees.
[image: new grid]

If you used the default interval when creating the Graticule, click on the **Intervals** tab and select the **Decimal Degrees** option, then enter **0.002** for the X and Y axis.
[image: interval]

Click on the **Labels** tab then click on **Additional Properties...**
[image: parameters]

Set the **Label type** to **Decimal Degrees** and show **3** decimal places.
[image: labels]

I'd question if the example image of what you want was actually generated by ArcMap.  I couldn't see a way of controlling a Calibrated Border to line up with the grid interval.  The options are limited.
[image: Calibrated border options]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS, you have to use the option "measured grid" while creating a new grid.

Comment: Can you add some more detail or step by step instructions to your answer? Would help OP as well as others who find this post in the future.